# NumberFormatException when trying to convert the contents of a String Array into an Integer to be stored in an ArrayList

Tags: java, numberformatexception

This is my current code:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayCurrency = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayRate = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> arraySymbol = new ArrayList<String>();

public void loadFile() {

    File file = new File("C://Users//me//Documents//TestingAssignment//Assignment 2 Part 2//src/currency2.txt");

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));

        String line = in.readLine().trim();

        while (line != null) {

            String[] parts = line.split(",");

            line = in.readLine(); 

            String currency = parts[0].trim();
            String rate = parts[1].trim();
            String symbol = parts[2].trim();


            int rateConverted = Integer.parseInt(rate);

            //int thisRate = rateConverted2;

            arrayCurrency.add(currency);
            arrayRate.add(rateConverted);
            arraySymbol.add(symbol);

        }

        for(String name:arrayCurrency) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }

        for(int name:arrayRate) {
            System.out.println(name);
        } 

        for(String name:arraySymbol) {
            System.out.println(name);
        } 

        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        String msg = e.getMessage();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }

}
```

I have gone through the code with a debugger. It happens when it attempts to convert the first number in the text file.

An example of how the .txt file is set out:

US Dollars, 1.60, $

I want to split this up into 3 different arrays. However, I am having a problem trying to convert `parts[1].trim();` into an Integer so that it can be stored in `ArrayList<Integer> arrayRate = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

The error message shown is: "For Input String:" 1.60".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1.6 is not an integer though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.6 is not an Integer. You will need to store it in a Double List and convert to double using methods of Double class.

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayRate = new ArrayList<>();
Double dnum = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Use this link for reference - https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-convert-string-to-double-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this if you want integer part only

```
String s = parts[1].trim();
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
int i = (int) d;
```

and if you want both part separately then do like below:

```
String s =parts[1].trim();
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
int i = (int) d;
double j=d-i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Amounts like "1.60" should be better represented as doubles, rather than integers.
I'd suggest you change your amount arrayList to `ArrayList<Double>` and parse the rate like below :

```
 double rateConverted = Double.parseDouble(rate);
```